# Неправильное отображение данных реестра в консоли C++

Tags: c++, консоль

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой отображения данных в консоли при использовании метода с функцией **RegQueryValueEx**. При извлечении данных из main (если напрямую вызывать функцию) все отображается корректно. Но если разместить функцию в методе, отображаются кракозябры.

Хочу сделать универсальный метод для доступа к реестру. При вызове **cout** в теле метода данные также отображаются нормально, как только они выводятся **cout** в main отображается бред.
Скорее всего это связано с кодировкой самой консоли, но я не уверен и обращаюсь к вам за помощью.
Среда VS2015.

Фрагмент последней версии с классом Registry:

```
ER_CODE Registry::GetOsVersion(HKEY mainKey, LPCTSTR keyPath, LPCTSTR keyValue, LPSTR &registryData)
{
    HKEY key;
    DWORD regtype;
    DWORD reg;
    TCHAR data[256];
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(mainKey, keyPath, NULL, KEY_READ, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
    if (RegQueryValueEx(key, keyValue, NULL, &regtype, (LPBYTE)&data, &reg) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (regtype == REG_SZ)
        {
            registryData = data;
            RegCloseKey(key);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        else return WARNING;
    }
    else return WARNING;
}
else return WARNING;
}

int main() 
{
    LPTSTR regData;
    ER_CODE eCode;
    Registry reg;
    eCode = reg.GetOsVersion(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"), TEXT("ProductName"), regData);
    if (eCode == SUCCESS)
    {
    printf("%-20s\n",regData);
    }
    system("pause");
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data - это локальная переменная, по выходу с функции она перестает существовать. присваивание вида `registryData = data;` копирует только указатель, но не самы данные. Следовательно, в строке `printf("%-20s\n",regData);` у Вас указатель на мусор (точнее - само значение указателя не поменялось, но вот память, куда он указывает, уже могла перетереться).

Что делать?

Нужно выделять память правильнее. Если два способа, либо выделить память прямо в main и передать указатель на эту память (`char data[256]` - это тоже выделение памяти, не объязательно malloc или new). Также, неплохо передать размер этой выделенной памяти внутрь функции, что бы она ее знала.

Второй способ - это функция сама выделяет память, но тогда нужно не забыть самому освободить память.

Comment: Третий способ - использовать `std::string`

Comment: С этим способом есть одна проблема. В коде используется TCHAR, но почему то майкрософт не сделала тип tstring. и это приходиться вводить ручками...

Comment: Так с этим все просто. Надо просто навсегда отказаться от однобайтовых строк.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. С проблемой разобрался